# how to convert a triple text file to RDF format

Tags: rdf, data-conversion, txt, turtle-rdf

I have a file which each line includes three parts which are separated via 'tab', please take a look at the following example of my input data:

```
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:common.topic.notable_for>   <fb:g.1q3sj7rb3>
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:common.topic.notable_types> <fb:m.0kpv1_>
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:music.group_member.membership>  <fb:m.0100zv6q>
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:people.person.nationality>  <fb:m.03_r3>
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:people.person.place_of_birth>   <fb:m.03_r3>
```

How can I convert the file ino a turtle/n3/owl or xml format?
The file is around 2GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values already seem to be legal URIs. All you need to do is add a full stop at the end of each line:

```
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:common.topic.notable_for>   <fb:g.1q3sj7rb3> .
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:common.topic.notable_types> <fb:m.0kpv1_> .
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:music.group_member.membership>  <fb:m.0100zv6q> .
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:people.person.nationality>  <fb:m.03_r3> .
<fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:people.person.place_of_birth>   <fb:m.03_r3> .
```

That's all. Your file is now legal [N-Triples](https://www.w3.org/TR/n-triples/) syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't the prefix have to be expanded to be legal N-Triples? Might be easier to prepend a prefix statement as well to make it legal Turtle.

Comment: if there exist some literals as the third part of lines, do I have to put them in <>?
for example, <fb:m.0100zv6s> <fb:people.person.name>  David .

Comment: @chrisis `fb:` is not a prefix here. It's surrounded by angle brackets, which makes it a full IRI.

Comment: @dinan I wasn't aware there would be literals - your example didn't show that. But no: literals should be surrounded by double quotes. `"David"`